# How to fix this scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification error?

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

I am using PHP version 7.2.19 and Laravel 5.6.39. I am getting this scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification error when I run composer install.

[image]

When I check the link it is not available and I also try to delete the scsuoft file manually but when I run composer install again the file is automatically added and I keep getting the same error.

Also, if I try composer require jeremykenedy/laravel-exception-notifier

[image]

Comment: On `https://packagist.org/packages/scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification` it says `This package is abandoned and no longer maintained. No replacement package was suggested.`

Comment: @Areg so what should I do?

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: The problem is that `scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification` is registered inside your `composer.json` file. Try to delete it from the composer file and then try again

Comment: tried above method by deleting ```scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification``` from composer.json and composer.lock , run ```composer update``` , now system crash, and simple command line such as ```php artisan laravel --version``` can't even run

Comment: there is no solution using composer for this things. the package is really hard to be change since it had been used and configured, the only solution is to download already existing vendor which have source code of scsuoft-laravel-exception-notification  then run composer install

Comment: here i attached the vendor.zip, you can download and extract this to the project directory

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VDSJTcROa3kH_RojObdfHKJ1Q4-zbWAB

if ok then dont run composer install, 
if not ok then run composer install

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer require jeremykenedy/laravel-exception-notifier`. After some digging i found there's no `scsuoft/laravel-exception-notification` anywhere.

Comment: at terminal same as the picture above

Comment: are you sure you used `jeremykenedy/laravel-exception-notifier` instead of `scsuoft/laravel-exception-notifier` ?